# How do I change the colour of the focus ring in a JCheckBox?

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

Our Swing GUI has a black panel with white controls. However the JCheckBox instance on the panel always shows the focus ring in black. It seems to ignore the foreground colour when rendering the focus ring. Here's an example, where I've set the content pane background to grey so that the focus ring is visible:

[image]

Here's the code I'm using:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ScratchSpace {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox("Hello cruel world");
                checkBox.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                checkBox.setOpaque(false);

                JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
                contentPane.setOpaque(true);
                contentPane.setBackground(new Color(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f));
                contentPane.add(checkBox);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

How can I tell a JCheckBox to render the focus ring in a specific colour? Ideally it would use the control's foreground colour.

Answer (score 4):

You could try changing the look and feel property `CheckBox.focus`, note, doing this will effect ALL `JCheckBox`s...

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestCheckBox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestCheckBox();
    }

    public TestCheckBox() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                UIManager.put("CheckBox.focus", Color.RED);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                frame.add(new JCheckBox("Hello world"));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I need to do this to just one panel - the rest of the app should not change. Can I change the UI property for a single component?

Comment: No, you will need to, unfortunately, create your own UI delegate and make your own adjustments, as it's entirely controlled from here.  You can override the `paintFocus` of the `WindowsCheckBoxUI`, for example, and make your own adjustments, but this will have issues if your decide to use a different look and feel...